# Database to store more than one primary key; sql vs nosql

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, nosql

I'm developing an app that needs a database with more than one primary key. Its architecture would consist in something like that:

```
PK == Primary Key

         | column1 | column2(PK) | columns3(PK) | column4(PK) | column5(PK)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
row1     | word    | string      | string       | string      |  string
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
row2     | word    | string      | string       | string      |  string
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
row3     | word    | string      | string       | string      |  string
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
row4     | word    | string      | string       | string      |  string
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
row5     | word    | string      | string       | string      |  string
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
rowN     | word    | string      | string       | string      |  string
```

The app will ask the database for the Word (in column1) that correspond to the string specified. The query would be something like that:

```
SELECT word 
FROM table 
WHERE columnN = 'string' 
LIMIT 1;
```

where `word` is the word on column1, `columnN` is the column 1,2,3,4 or 5 and `string` is a string that could be contained on `columnN`

The database will contain million of rows so that I need more that one primary key in order to get the `word` that correspond to the string very fast.

I've created a database with this structure (but only one primary key on `column2`) and 3,000,000 rows. When I search the word that correspond to the string contained on the column with the primary key, the DB responds me in less than half-second but if I search a word that correspond to a string contained on a column without primary key, the DB responds me on more than half-hour (unacceptable)

So my question is:

How should I structure the database in order to get the response fast independently of the column that contains the string?

I've been reading about noSql databases but I don't know if that's what I need because the database I need is fully relational

**Edit:** It must be free solution and I have to be able to run it on a domestic computer

Comment: your question is not really about primary keys.What you are looking for are indexes / unique indexes. Try creating indexes on all of your `columnN` columns and then test the performance.

Comment: Please remove the sql-server tag since the app doesn't run on Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

I think that adding too many primary keys is not your solution here. Notice that normally primary keys have a size limitation, so you will bump into a road block sooner than later.

What you might be needing here is either a non-clustered index or a vendor-specific technology such as Full-Text Search in MS SQL Server which creates (IMO and by experience) very efficient indexes

Comment: Thaks leo, but I nedd a Free solution and I have to be able to do it on a Raspberry-Pi

Comment: @SalvaCorts you're welcome but...what do you mean by "free solution"? Oracle supports something similar called Oracle Text by the way and MySQL as well

Comment: I mean whitout cost, I've been using MySQL and I had that Problem. do you thing Oracle Text will be the answer?

Comment: @Leo - I don't think full text search is really required in comparisons like `columnN='string'`. Indexes should easily do the trick

Comment: @ughai that's what I meant, its a full relational database so as I said, if `columnN` is `column2` (the only PK I created on my studio) it give me the `word` fast but if `columnN` is different from 2, it takes a lot of time

Comment: the reason its fast is becuase there is an index on column2 , if you create an index on other column as well, the `SELECT` with filter on that column would be fast as well

Comment: @ughai I never said it was required, but I favored full-text search because he is talking about 3m rows and non-clustered indexes are very expensive to re-build